# High Performance Service with Java, CDI and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm writing a realtime data service with Java EE7 and MongoDB. The service should be highly scalable.

What's the best practice for the persistance layer regarding thread safety and avoiding bottlenecks?

Right now I have something like:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public PersistanceLayer {
    @PostContruct
    public void connectToDb() {
        // Connect to db
    }

    public List<Stuff> getStuffFromDb() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

What about thread safety regarding @ApplicationScoped?
Will this be a performance bottleneck regarding @ApplicationScoped?
How does the performance compare to having the overhead to connect to the db for every request?

```
@RequestScoped
public PersistanceLayer {
    @PostContruct
    public void connectToDb() {
        // Connect to db
    }

    public List<Stuff> getStuffFromDb() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

How about taking the second approach and provide pooled connections?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this question has to do with CDI.  The same would apply if you were doing manual singleton management.  CDI doesn't provide any specific concurrency capabilities.

The MongoDB client for Java internally uses a pooled connection set (100 is the default min pool size).

Looking at this note, it seems like the best approach is to have a separate bean that is responsible for giving out connections, e.g. `myBean.getDB("dbname");`  You then need to call `db.requestStart();` to essentially begin your session, and `db.requestDone();` to give your session back to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Well your issue can be complicated.. Let me try to explain:

With the first approach you will have one Object instace that leave connection open.. Once the application is up. And has one connection so it wouldn't be the right way to do it.

The Second approach will create object PersistanceLayer for every request and open new connection which is also not something you need..

I think the best way is the Combined approach.

It should be something like Singelton(or Application Level scope) because you don't need to create object for every request, You just need one class that provide you services..

The only thing you want to create is taking connection for each action and close it.. So it should be something like that:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public PersistanceLayer {

    public List<Stuff> getStuffFromDb() {
        try {
            ConnectDB();
            DoYourQueryAndGetResult();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Handle exception
        } finally {
            CloseConnection();
        }

        return ...;
    }
}
```

Please notice that this persistance layer should be something like Utils Class that contain static methods or Should be Singelton and it this case you will have one instance for persistance layer that can hanle few connection, Or Utils static class that you don't even need an instance

Hope that helps